Mounting drive with mount command and fstab do not work as intended
I have two external USB drives which I would like to be mounted to specific directories which are owned by my user. A script runs on startup which mounts all my drives in their specific locations using the mount command. All the ntfs drives are being mounted with the right user permissions but the exfat and fat32 drives have write permissions only for root. I tried chown recursively but it has not worked so I modified /etc/fstab/ for my exfat drive but it is also not mounting with the right permissions. I have added my user to the root group but I still do not have permissions to use the mount command or write to the folders without sudo.
Here is the script I am using to mount the drives
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/G -o users
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /media/C -o users
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/F -o users
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/D -o users
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/E -o users,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000,dmask=0000,fmask=0000

And here is my /etc/fstab/
UUID=BC44-0521 /media/E exfat rw,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000,dmask=0000,fmask=0000 0 0

I am using Manjaro Linux which is dual booted with a Windows installation.

Why do you have a "script that runs mount" if you already have a fstab? Isn't that kinda the job of fstab?

I discovered fstab later so before that I was running that script. But neither of them is working as I want it to.
